# How to upgrade from Yosemite to Monterey?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade, monterey

I have a Macbook Air, early 2014, running Yosemite. I went to the App Store, looked for Monterey, didn't find it, got a link somewhere else and finally found it. Yet, when I try to install it, it says my machine is incompatible with Monterey. Yosemite is unusable due to outdated apps, lack of TLS certificates etc. What could I do?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, Monterey is not compatible with my Macbook Air, but Big Sur is and should be enough for our needs.

Here is how I installed it:

- I found [this page in Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). It has links to hidden versions of macOS and shows the compatibility between the versions. Very helpful!
- By clicking on a link, I opened it in the App Store.
- The App Store, however, required authenticating with Apple ID. I tried, but I have two-factor authentication, and apparently, this version of the App Store does not support it.

  - Here you can try to disable two-factor authentication through an iPhone, but I couldn't, for unknown reasons.
  - So I created another Apple ID account, only to install the new OS version.
  - Later I learned [this workaround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283014/mzfinance-badlogin-macappstore-message-error-when-signing-into-apple-id/283047#283047) from @grg's comment below. I didn't try it but seems even better than creating another account.

In the end, it worked. If you find you need a different version based on your needs or hardware, [this other guide can help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/5472).

Comment: Older operating systems that existed before two-factor still support it as a suffix: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283047/37797

Comment: @grg oh, that's useful! Thank you so much for sharing!